# Standard/accepted Microsoft ASP.NET Mobile Development Practices across a Variety of Devices?

Tags: asp.net, mobile

What's the current defacto standard for ASP.NET mobile development across a wide variety of devices (not just Microsoft devices)? I've researched http://www.asp.net/mobile/ and have looked into both Control Adapters and Mobile Controls.  These solutions are workable however the technologies seem outdated by way of mobile devices tested (old ones), last updated project dates, etc.

I suppose Microsoft might be focused on their own Windows mobile devices; however I want to hit a variety of devices in a generic way (e.g. **mostly various Blackberry devices**, also iPhone, etc) for the web - basically things that might not render a regular web page well or at all.
(However I've noted from other threads that iPhone etc can often browse the regular website version).

Is there another website I should be researching for ASP.NET mobile development, or this seemingly outdated stuff the best I will get?

Comment: I think most important resource is [Mobile Web Application toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interestesd in the [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com).  It uses the App_Browsers and .browser file mechanism within ASP.Net to identify browser capabilities.  These guys are good at keeping the file up to date with the latest devices and their capabilities

Answer (score 2):

The newest Blackberry browser, iPhone, Palm and Android devices use WebKit based browsers. If you write a website that works at low resolution, and is standards compliant, you shouldn't need any special toolkits.

If you want a more native look and feel on each device, browser-sniffing and customized CSS should do the trick.